# Classical-quantum channel and entropy of output state

Tags: quantum-information, entropy

**The setting:**

Consider a channel $N$ defined by measuring its input state in some basis $B$ and outputting a density matrix $\tau_i$ for the $i^{th}$ outcome.

$$N(\rho) = \sum_i \langle i\vert \rho \vert i\rangle\tau_i$$

Let $\rho_D$ be obtained by dropping all the off-diagonal entries of $\rho$, when $\rho$ is expressed in the basis $B$. Let $\Phi$ and $\Phi_D$ be the purifications of $\rho$ and $\rho_D$ respectively. It is [claimed](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0106052) (between (5) and (6) of the linked reference) that the following entropies are equal

$$S((N\otimes I)\Phi) = S((N\otimes I)\Phi_D) \tag{1}$$

**My attempt at proving this so far:**

I can see that the $N(\rho) = N(\rho_D)$. Let us write explicitly $\rho_D = \sum_i\lambda_i\vert i\rangle\langle i \vert$ and $\rho = \sum_i\lambda_{ij}\vert i\rangle\langle j \vert$. Note that $\lambda_{ii} = \lambda_i$. Then we have

$$\Phi_D = \sum_{i,j}\sqrt{\lambda_i\lambda_j}\vert i\rangle\langle j\vert \otimes \vert i\rangle\langle j\vert $$
$$\Phi = \sum_{i,j,i',j'}\sqrt{\lambda_{ij}\lambda_{i'j'}}\vert i\rangle\langle i'\vert \otimes \vert j\rangle\langle j'\vert$$

Applying $(N\otimes I)$, we get
$$(N\otimes I)\Phi_D = \sum_i\lambda_i\tau_i\otimes \vert i\rangle\langle i\vert$$
$$(N\otimes I)\Phi = \sum_{i,j,j'}\sqrt{\lambda_{ij}\lambda_{ij'}}\tau_i \otimes \vert j\rangle\langle j'\vert$$
As for entropies, we can see that
$$S((N\otimes I)\Phi_D) = H(\lambda) + \sum_i\lambda_i S(\tau_i) = S(\rho_D) + \sum_i\lambda_i S(\tau_i)$$

However, I cannot really say much about the entropy of $S((N\otimes I)\Phi)$. How do I proceed to prove (1)?